# Loop array with vue in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

can anyone help me on the following problem please. 
I'd like to run a simple array via a loop within vue in laravel to give all the array values out in a table. This is my code I adjusted from a tutorial I found in the internet: enter code here

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Coffeetypes</h1>
        
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="cctyp in cctypes" v-bind:key="cctyp.id">
                    <td>{{ cctyp.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ cctyp.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ cctyp.description }}</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            
            cctypes: [],
            cctyp: {
                id: '',
                name: '',
                description: '',
                created_by: '',
                updated_by: ''
            }, 
            id: '',
            pagination: {},
            edit: false
        };
    }, 

    created() {
        this.fetchCCTypes();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchCCTypes(){
            fetch('api/CCTypes')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                this.cctypes = res.data;
            });
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

The problem is, that there is no filling in the table.

Comment: what happens when you print the array directly in the template 
`{{cctypes}}`

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's the double `.then()...` in your fectch method ... you should console.log your data first ...